# Avoid null pointers while accessing objects in a tree hierarchy of classes

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, c++11

I have to work with a tree based hierarchy of objects where I need to access the deepest element that contains the data required by the application. I'm not sure if the previous statement explains in its best the problem itself so its better to present it with an example. Given the following scenario:

```
class A {
private:
    B* _b;
public:
    B* getB() {return _b;}
};

class B {
private:
    C* _c;
public:
    C* getC() {return _c;}
};

class C {
private:
    int _n;
public:
    int getN() {return _n;}
};
```

The desired operation would be to access **n** via **A**. So I would call the following:

```
A foo;
foo.getB()->getC()->getN();
```

The problem comes when any of the parts of the path are null we end up having a core dump. In the above scenario if B is null we end up in a core dump scenario.

Therefore I seek help and advice on any strategy or pattern that I can use to avoid this core dumps scenarios. If the path is extremely big I end up checking every single pointer if its valid and end up having really ugly code and also risk that I might have missed checking a part of the path. **Note: I do not have access to change the implementation of the hierarchy of classes (A,B,C) as they are generated code and I do not have access to change the generator.** Changing the previous would be my preferred solution but unfortunately I cannot.

Comment: Why is the pointer invalid in the first place? What is the lifetime of those objects? Who manages those pointers? Are they part of any invariant?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately because you designed your architecture in this way the code is going to be ugly. C++ has no "safe navigation operator" like something like C# does. You would have to implement that yourself. But a much better alternative would be to significantly refactor your architecture. You should try your best to avoid having coupling that is several layers deep, because dealing with them is always going to be a nightmare.

Comment: Not an answer, but:  The Law of Demeter suggests that when you find yourself having to chain multiple dereferences like that, it's time to refactor your API so that you no longer have to do so:   http://www.cpptips.com/demeter2

Comment: @JeremyFriesner In "Clean Code" it is called "[train wreck](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2011/12/30/how-many-train-wrecks-are-lurking-in-your-code)".

Answer (score 4):

In order to avoid having null pointers, you may want to establish a class-invariant that the member is never null. This can be achieved with following steps:

1. Encapsulate access to the member so that nothing outside the class can set the member. You've already achieved this through the use of private access. Just make sure that you pass/return a reference or a pointer to the member from a member function to the outside.
2. Ensure that no member nor friend function ever sets the member to null.
3. Also ensure that the member is always initialised. This is achieved by use of a custom constructor. Example:

---

```
class A {
    B* b;
public:
    A(B* b) : b(b) {
        if (!b) {
            // unlike indirection through null pointer, an exception can
            // be caught and (potentially) handled gracefully at runtime
            throw std::runtime_error("Naughty!");
        }
    }

    // following prevents passing null literal at compile time
    A(std::nullptr_t) = delete; // nullptr
    A(int)            = delete; // 0

    // since it is never null, we can safely return a reference
    B& getB() {return *b;}
}
```

While references have the nice property of not being ever null, they are tricky as members, since they are also not assignable. As an argument to a constructor, they are tricky since it is generally not conventional or expected for a class object to keep references to objects passed into a constructor. As such, I advocate the use of pointers in this case even when null is undesirable.

> Note: I do not have access to change the implementation of the hierarchy of classes (A,B,C) as they are generated code and I do not have access to change the generator.

In this case you may instead wrap the generated classes with better classes:

```
class AWrapper {
    A a;
    // custom implementation that encapsulates A
}
```

---

If null pointers are valid values that cannot be avoided, then such invariant is of course not possible. In such case, you must always check whether the pointer is null before indirecting through it:

```
if (B* b = foo.getB())
    if (C* c = b->getC())
        c->getN();
```

Another thing that you might consider is whether all these pointers are necessary. Perhaps it would be simpler if the classes contained each other instead of indirectly referring to one another.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test all along the way:

```
A foo;
B* BPrt = foo.getB();
if (BPrt)
{
    C* CPtr = BPrt->getC();
    if (CPtr)
    {
        int n = CPtr->getN();
        ...
```

Comment: This is a technical answer for potentially a bigger design issue. Chances are, OP would be better off fixing the design. Also this multiple nesting is a pain to read, and it should not be suggested.

Comment: @SergeyA Sure, but the OP is about avoiding using `nullptr` when they are used as a sentinel value.  This answers that question.  You want to go in an fix all the OP's problems - great!  But that doesn't make this answer incorrect.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer. OP is already aware they can do multiple check, the question is specifically how to avoid doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C {
private:
    int _n;
public:
    int getN() {return _n;}
};

class B {
private:
    C* _c;
public:
    C* getC() {return _c;}
};


class A {
private:
    B* _b;
public:
    B* getB() {return _b;}
};

int main(void);
int main() {
    static B b;
    static C c;
    static A foo; 
    unsigned int n;
    B *bPtr; C *cPtr;

    /* --RECODE (CHAIN-CALL): foo.getB()->getC()->getN();-- */
    bPtr = (B *) (foo.getB());
    cPtr = (C *) (bPtr ? bPtr->getC() : 0);
    n    = (int) (cPtr ? cPtr->getN() : 0);
    /* --USE (CAST) and (TERNARY) instead of (CHAIN-CALL)-- */

    cout << n << endl;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Those casts aren't needed.

Comment: In this case, that's correct. But the form is presented that preserves the reversal of the code from call chain to cast-ternary which can be grown to handle `n` cases of call-chaining.

Comment: What do the `static`s add here? I can't imagine a scenario where a local variable in `main` would benefit from being `static`.

Comment: It's not really necessary here—just a leftover from the original code I worked with.

Answer (score 0):

If the classes cannot be changed then the checking could be done via a template:

```
template <typename T, typename A, typename ...Args>
auto recurse(T t, A a, Args... args)
{
    if (!t)
        throw std::exception{};
    auto next = (t->*a)();
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) > 0)
        return recurse(next, args...);
    else
        return next;
}
```

[Then call as follows](https://godbolt.org/z/RJaWOV):

```
recurse(&foo, &A::getB, &B::getC, &C::getN);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not with a pointer being `null`. That is in-fact good as it mostly crashes at runtime. What if it's not `null` but has been previously freed/deleted ? The usage will probably lead to Undefined Behaviour.

A better way would be to use references if you can:

```
class A
{
private:
  B& _b;
public:
  A(B& b): _b{b} {}
  B& getB ()
  {
    return _b;
  }
};
```

Or something like that. Then you at-least don't have anything dangling (unless you are also using pointers somewhere).

If you have to use pointers then use one of the smart-pointers - see if `std::unique_ptr` solves if for you. If not then for shared ownership use `std::shared_ptr` and so on. Also ensure the way you initialise objects don't lead to a default null there.

Comment: Reference type data members are troublesome. Because they can't be reseated it makes it hard to implement assignment and move semantics. Additionally, it's not clear that one of the pointers isn't *intended* to be `nullptr`.

Comment: This is ill-advised in general and also not necessarily applicable to OP (there is no clarification on the source of null pointers). Member references really complicate dealing with the class, and they should be reserved for truly necessary cases. Often a non-owning pointer is a better alternative.

Comment: Fair enough, I incorrectly thought the OP wanted to ensure that it shouldn't be a null or a design that is such. I misunderstood it as if you are checking for null-ness then you are probably not sure when you should be using it and then maybe it's not null but garbage.

Answer (score -1):

You can make sure that your pointers are always initialized, if possible:

```
class C {
private:
    int _n = 0;
public:
    int getN() {return _n;}
};


class B {
private:
    static C default_c;
    C* _c = &default_c;
public:
    C& getC() {return *_c;}
};

C B::default_c; // An out-of-line static member definition is required.

class A {
private:
    static B default_b;
    B* _b = &default_b;
public:
    B& getB() {return *_b;}
};

B A::default_b; // An out-of-line static member definition is required.

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a.getB().getC().getN() << '\n';
}
```

Note that pointers make better members than references because the references break value semantics and make your class non-assignable.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to assume the pointers can always be meaningfully initialized. And it doesn't account for the situation where one of the pointers may be made `nullptr` later.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am note sure if your comment is relevant to my particular code.

Comment: That might be a good and valuable advice, assuming default objects make sense for OP. Unfortunately, OP has really given us no indication of what the desired behavior actually is.

Comment: It's specifically addressed to this particular post. Your answer is to always initialize the pointers but I don't believe there is any indication that is possible for OPs case and certainly isn't generally something that is meaningful. Objects represents concepts, information, behaviors, etc. This solution assumes that a global non-`const` instance of each of these objects is meaningful but that's not usually true.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It seems to me your comments are misplaced. You may like to post you own answer. Feel free to disagree.

Answer (score -1):

Did you consider:

```
try {
foo.getB()->getC()->getN();
}
catch(...)
{
    //Here you know something is Null
}
```

That seems the simplest safest,when dealing with existing code.

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer results in undefined behavior. It is not required to throw an exception.